# Edit and make class-wc-widget-featured-products.php update-proof

Tags: widgets, plugins, child-theme

Within the class-wc-widget-featured-products.php file I need to Remove this on Line 101:

`<?php if ( $r->post->post_title ) echo get_the_title( $r->post->ID ); else echo $r->post->ID; ?>`

and Remove:
`</a> <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>`

And change the UL tag to a DIV and delete the li tags, which is fine to do within the core file... but can anyone tell me how I would implement this in the functions file to keep my changes from being deleted with every woocommerce update?

I tried adding the edited file to a woocommerce>classes>widgets file structure within my child theme but I've just read that this only works with template files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks